# Linux & Windows: Using Large Files to save physical memory

Tags: c++, windows, linux

Good afternoon, We have implemented a C++ cKeyArray class to test whether we can use the Large File API to save physical memory. During Centos Linux testing, we found that the Linux File API was just as fast as using  the heap for random access processing. Here are the numbers: for a 2,700,000 row SQL database where the KeySize for each row is 62 bytes,

cKeyArray class using LINUX File API
BruteForceComparisons = 197275 BruteForceTimeElapsed = 1,763,504,445 microsecs 
Each BruteForce Comparisons requires two random access, there the mean time required for each random access = 1,763,504,445 microsecs / (2 * 197275) = 4470 microsecs

Heap , no cKeyArray class

BruteForceComparisons = 197275 BruteForceTimeElapsed = 1,708,442,690microsecs 
the mean time required for each random access = 4300 microsecs.

On 32 bit Windows,the numbers are,

cKeyArray class using Windows File API
BruteForceComparisons = 197275 BruteForceTimeElapsed = 9243787 millisecs
the mean time for each random access is 23.4 millisec

Heap, no cKeyArray class
BruteForceComparisons = 197275 BruteForceTimeElapsed = 2,141,941 millisecs 
the mean time requires for each random access is 5.4 millisec

We are wondering why the Linux cKeyArray numbers are just as good the Linux heap numbers while on 32 bit Windows the mean heap random access time is  4 times as fast the cKeyArray Windows File API. Is  there some way we can speed up the Windows cKeyArray File API?

Previouly, we received a lot of good suggestions from Stack Overflow on using the Windows Memory Mapped File API. Based on these Stack Overflow suggestions we have implemented a Memory Mapped File MRU caching class which functions properly.

Because we want to devlop a cross-platform solution, we want to do due diligence to see why the Linux File API is so fast? Thank you. We are trying to post a portion of  the cKeyArray class implementation below.

```
#define KEYARRAY_THRESHOLD 100000000   
// Use file instead of memory if requirement is above this number


cKeyArray::cKeyArray(long RecCount_,int KeySize_,int MatchCodeSize_, char* TmpFileName_) {
    RecCount=RecCount_;
    KeySize=KeySize_;
    MatchCodeSize=MatchCodeSize_;
    MemBuffer=0;
    KeyBuffer=0;
    MemFile=0;
    MemFileName[0]='\x0';
    ReturnBuffer=new char[MatchCodeSize + 1];   
    if (RecCount*KeySize<=KEYARRAY_THRESHOLD) {     
        InMemory=true;
        MemBuffer=new char[RecCount*KeySize];
        memset(MemBuffer,0,RecCount*KeySize);
    } else {
        InMemory=false;
        strcpy(MemFileName,TmpFileName_);
        try {
            MemFile=
                              new cFile(MemFileName,cFile::CreateAlways,cFile::ReadWrite);
        }
        catch (cException e)
        {
            throw e;    
        }
        try {
            MemFile->SetFilePointer(
                               (int64_t)(RecCount*KeySize),cFile::FileBegin);
        }
        catch (cException e)
        {
            throw e;    
        }
        if (!(MemFile->SetEndOfFile()))
            throw cException(ERR_FILEOPEN,MemFileName);

        KeyBuffer=new char[KeySize];
    }
}

char *cKeyArray::GetKey(long Record_) {
        memset(ReturnBuffer,0,MatchCodeSize + 1);   
    if (InMemory) {
        memcpy(ReturnBuffer,MemBuffer+Record_*KeySize,MatchCodeSize);
    } else {
        MemFile->SetFilePointer((int64_t)(Record_*KeySize),cFile::FileBegin);
        MemFile->ReadFile(KeyBuffer,KeySize);
        memcpy(ReturnBuffer,KeyBuffer,MatchCodeSize);   
    }
    return ReturnBuffer;
}


uint32_t cKeyArray::GetDupeGroup(long Record_) {
    uint32_t DupeGroup(0);
    if (InMemory) {
         memcpy((char*)&DupeGroup,
                         MemBuffer+Record_*KeySize + MatchCodeSize,sizeof(uint32_t)); 
    } else {
        MemFile->SetFilePointer(
                        (int64_t)(Record_*KeySize + MatchCodeSize) ,cFile::FileBegin);
        MemFile->ReadFile((char*)&DupeGroup,sizeof(uint32_t));
    }
    return DupeGroup;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a cross-platform solution; just refactor the platform-specific stuff into separate files.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, Are you suggesting that we refactor the Linux file API into one file and the Windows memory mapped file implementation into another file? We are puzzled why the Linux File API is faster than the the Windows File API? Do you  have clues about this ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: No. Use memory-mapped in both cases with the same interface, then fill in the implementation for each.

Comment: That is what I do: write the same function names but one set in os-support-unix.cpp and another set in os-support-win32.cpp

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, Thank you for your answer. Eric Melski just explained what Linux is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: @Zan Lynx, I agree with your suggestion about two os-specific files. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your memory-mapped solution should be as much as 10x faster than the file solution even in Linux. That is the speed I experience in my test cases.

Each file access system call takes hundreds of CPU cycles to complete. Time which your program could be using to do real work.

One explanation for why the speeds are similar could be that your memory map has not been used before. When a memory mapped page is accessed for the first time it must be assigned to a physical page of RAM and zeroed out or if it is a disk file it must be loaded from disk into RAM. All of that takes a considerable amount of time.

If you touch (read or write a value) each 4K of RAM before using it you should see a significant speed increase in the memory map.

Comment: @Zan Lynx, I just accepted your answer. I was wondering how your memory-mapped method can be 10X fater than the file solution in Linux. I have found on Windows that memory mapped file implemntation with MRU caching is just as fast as the heap for 2,700,00 row of data where which row contains 62 bytes. based

Comment: @Zan Lynx, Based on our testing of the Window memory mapped file caching , we find that memory mapped file caching is just as fast as the fast as the heap solution. Since you are getting a 10X improvment in Windows and Linux, that implies your memory mapped implemenation is at least 2.5 times faster than the heap. How your your memory mapped implementation beat the speed of the heap solution. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Frank: Not 10x faster than the heap. I find memory map to be 10x faster than using pread/pwrite or seek/read/write.

Comment: @Zan Lynx, Thank you for the clarification. I apologize for the misunderstanding. Actually, your post doesn't mention anything about the heap. Since our testing methodolgies differ and you have much more experience and expertise than I possess, I should not compare my test results with your test results. Thank you.

Comment: @Zan Lynx, I am trying to figure out how the Linux memory map can be 10X faster than using Linux read,write,lseek. On this thread, Eric Melski states that "most Linux filesystems actually implement the standard I/O interfaces as thin wrappers around the page cache. That means that even though you haven't explicitly memory mapped the file, the system is still treating it as though it were memory mapped under-the-covers". If Linux is treating the file as though it were memory mapped, what memory mapped technique are using to obtain 10X faster results than Linux read/write/lseek? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Using the seek/read/write means using a system call for each one. A system call is expensive. It has to save all the user stack, CPU registers, switch to CPU Ring 0, etc. A memory map, when the memory page is mapped, is a simple memory read or write.

Comment: @Zan Lynx, Thank you for your reply. I understand why your Linux memory mappping numbers are significantly faster than using Linux read, write , lseek. How do your Linux memory mapping numbers compare to reading and writing to the heap, provided that there is sufficient heap memory? Also, do your Linux memory mapping numbers vary depending on whether you are doing random accesses versus sequential accesses. Thank you

Comment: @Frank: The heap is RAM just like the memory map, so the speed is very similar. The advantage is that a memory map can be much larger than the amount of RAM in the system and the OS will swap file pieces in and out automatically. In a unreferenced map sequential access is much faster because of disk read-ahead. If the map contents are already loaded into RAM then there is no speed difference between random and sequential.

Comment: @Zan Lynx, Thank you for answering my questions. We are finding on Centos Linux that the heap speed is similar to the memory map speed.Thank you for sharing your expertise with us.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, the OS aggressively caches file data in main memory -- so although you haven't explicitly allocated memory for the file contents, they are nevertheless stored in RAM.  Here's a decent link with some more information about the [page cache](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files) -- only one thing is missing from that description, which is that most Linux filesystems actually implement the standard I/O interfaces as thin wrappers around the page cache.  That means that even though you haven't explicitly memory mapped the file, the system is still treating it as though it were memory mapped under-the-covers.  That's why you see roughly equivalent performance with either approach.

I second the suggestion to factor the platform-specific stuff out, and use whichever appropach is fastest for each platform.  Be sure to benchmark -- don't ever make assumptions about performance.

Comment: I just accepted your answer. So I guess we have to use the memory mapped implementation which Stack Overflow showed us how to do. Thank you for your answer.